# Group/form chains of all next greater elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

### Group/Form chains of all next greater elements from the value at the current index
(merges into if any existing chain)

Eg: Consider piles of some objects
----------

A[ 1 3 2 4 5 1 2 3 7]

---

Starting with the first index A[0] = 1

---

Next greater to 1 => 3

---

Next greater to 3 => 4

---

Next greater to 4 => 5

---

Next greater to 5 => 7

---

So we get our first chain [1 3 4 5 7]

---

Now for the second group, [1 3] already done start with A[2] (0 based)

---

A[2] = 2, Next greater to 2 =>4

---

4 already included so it's obvious that it will follow it for rest of the interaction so this now merges to chain1 at the value 4,

---

so G2 will have [2 4]

---

**I want this all to be represented as a tree as shown in image**
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTUD6.jpg)

I tried using, Naive way which is **O(N*N)**,
I tried to improve using **stock span problem** but I couldn't figure out how to achieve it in at **max
O(N log N)**

Comment: What does next greater element mean?

Comment: To correspond to the figure, G3 should be [1 2 3 7] I guess

Comment: Yes, it should be [1 2 3 7]

Comment: @CanBayar next greater here means, we only have to move up (i.e to a greater value after the current index if any).

Comment: You mentioned the stack span problem, which can be solved in O(n logn). I don't understand the relationship with your problem here. Maybe you just want, for a given index `i`, to find index `j` such that `j-i` is minimum and `a[j] > a[i] `  ?

Comment: I do not understand the creation of G2, please add some more explanation... Your "clarity" image isn't explaining anything really.

Comment: @Damien see now.

Comment: @Yonlif I have included more details, see now if It's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will illustrate how to do this but not give you code.

You start with a list:

```
1 3 2 4 5 1 2 3 7
```

Here it is with positions added so we can talk about it more easily.

```
1 3 2 4 5 1 2 3 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

What we want is a new array of "position of the next largest element" that looks like this:

```
1 3 2 4 5 1 2 3 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 3 3 4 8 6 7 8 x
```

That last array has all of the information needed to construct your desired tree.  The challenge is how to generate that array efficiently.

We will generate it by walking from the back of the array backwards.  Answering the necessary question in `O(log(n))` at each step.  The data structure that I will describe is a variant on a [Skip List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).  It will tell us, in an ordered search by value, the lowest index at which anything bigger than that value can be found.  What we do is search it for our value in time `O(log(n))` then insert the fact that this value can be found in time `O(log(n))`.

As described in that article, a skip-list is a linked list of data.  And then a higher linked list of data summarizing something about the lower data.  with "skips".  Then a higher linked list on that.  Each data point goes to a height.  With half the points at height 0 (bottom list only), half at height 1, a quarter at height 2 and so on.  The whole data structure winds up being of size `n + n/2 + n/4 + ...` which is around `2n` in size.  All operations complete in an average of `log(n)` operations.

I will draw it without the necessary pointers to walk the data structure with each level being a row.  What you can do visually by going `right/left/down/up` need pointers in your program.  Our actual nodes will always look like `(value, first index met or exceeded)`.  (You will see that the node values may be stale, but this will be OK.)

Now in a skiplist you normally have the height of a node assigned randomly.  On average this works out.  But I will use the highest power of 2 that divides the value as my height.  That achieves a good distribution of heights for this example without the confusing random choices.

The trick is that when we read the skiplist, we start at the top and travel to the right then down until we find a value bigger than or equal to the one we are looking for.  We then travel left and down (left is that value is still greater than the one we want, down otherwise) and take the minimum index along the second path we find.  When we insert we always try to move up and then to the left recording the newly inserted index along that trail.

Now to make the trail of operations clear, I will add to my data structure the path that was taken during this operation.  Which means the following operations:

- `l`ooking for a higher value to start my search for the next index.
- `s`earching for the next index.  (I switch as soon as I find this, so there might be no `l` at all if the first thing I look at is part of the `s`earch.)
- `i`nserting a new node (since this is in a 2-d linked list structure you also have updates to neighbor pointers that I did not show).  This happens right before the last `s` and then go straight up.  But only if the value is new to us.
- `u`pdating something about a node.  These start to the left of the last `s`earch or `i`nsert then try to move up then left.  There will no updates if this is a new smallest value.

Now remember, we started with:

```
1 3 2 4 5 1 2 3 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

The first fact that we want in our skiplist is that the value `7` can be found at position `8`.  That fact is at height 0 so our skiplist looks like:

```
next: [x]
skip: (7,8)i
```

Next we have the fact that `3` can be found at position `7`.  The search for the next highest value is trivial.  We insert another fact at level 0 and get the following:

```
next: [8,x]
skip: (3,7)i  (7,8)s
```

Next the value `2` can be found at position `6`.  This introduces a new level.

```
next: [6,7,8,x]
skip: (2,6)i
      (2,6)i  (3,7)s  (7,8)
```

Next the value `1` can be found at position `5`.

```
next: [5,6,7,8,x]
skip:         (2,6)s
      (1,5)i  (2,6)s  (3,7)  (7,8)
```

Now the value `5` occurs at position `4`.  Since this is the first complicated one the letters indicate that we `l`ooked for where to start our search at the `(2,6)` at the top, then goes down, right, right.  Then we `s`earched only `(7,8)`.  We then `i`nsert and the following `u`pdate traveled left, left, up.  Note that the stale `(1,5)` in the bottom left will never give us a wrong conclusion because any search that hits it will have found a `(2,4)` first so we know to use the index of `4` rather than the stale `5`.

```
next: [8,5,6,7,8,x]
skip:         (2,4)lu
      (1,5)   (2,4)lu (3,4)lu (5,4)i  (7,8)s
```

Now `4` can be found at position `3`.  The read this time went down, left, left to find the starting `(5,4)`.  Our insert went one back then traveled straight up to create a new level.  We have lots of stale data we did not touch.

```
next: [4,8,5,6,7,8,x]
skip:                         (4,3)i
              (2,4)l          (4,3)i
      (1,5)   (2,4)l  (3,4)l  (4,3)i  (5,4)s  (7,8)
```

Next, `2` can be found at position `2`.  Those records existed so this is an `u`pdate.

```
next: [3,4,8,5,6,7,8,x]
skip:                         (4,3)s
              (2,2)u          (4,3)s
      (1,5)   (2,2)u  (3,4)s  (4,3)s  (5,4)   (7,8)
```

We are almost there!  `3` can now be found at position `1`.  Our search went straight down.  Then we found the root index, updated it then went left, up.

```
next: [3,3,4,8,5,6,7,8,x]
skip:                         (4,3)s
              (2,1)u          (4,3)s
      (1,5)   (2,1)u  (3,1)i  (4,3)s (5,4)   (7,8)
```

And now for the very last record we search down, left, down, left.  For completeness I will update the data structure to include it as well, though we are never going to look again.

```
next: [1,3,3,4,8,5,6,7,8,x]
skip:                         (4,3)s
              (2,1)           (4,3)s
      (1,0)u  (2,1)s  (3,1)s  (4,3)s   (5,4)   (7,8)
```

And the final state of the skip list says that the first value of at least 1 is at `0`, the first value of at least `2` or `3` is at `1`, the first value of at least `4` is at `3`, the first value of at least `5` is at `4`.  And the first value of at least `7` is at `8`.

Comment: Thanks! for your efforts, in the final array, I want all such chains, your explanation seems to be generating one such chain which can also be generated by maintaining a stack of next greater elements, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/.

Comment: For the above, the final answer will obviously have all the indices,
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5 , 8 ]   [2, 4 -> merges to First at index 4 ] [6 ,7  , 8 -> merges to first at index 8]